# how to get cursor position using GetSelection in text service framework windows8 application?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, text-services-framework

```
HRESULT         hr;
TF_SELECTION    tfSelection;
ULONG           uFetched;
//Obtain the default selection. 
hr = _pContext->GetSelection(ec, TF_DEFAULT_SELECTION, 1, &tfSelection, &uFetched);
UINT ar=(UINT)uFetched;
if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && (uFetched > 0))
{
    UINT ar=(UINT)uFetched;
    //Work with the selection. 
    //Release the selection range object. 
    tfSelection.range->Release();
}
```

Hi all. I am implementing this code in the DoEditSession method.  When I try to get the selection, I always get a value of 1 for `uFetched`. But the cursor position is not coming?

I am developing a text service for windows RT using Tsf interface. I
have integrated libraries that suggests words based on letters we type
in the candidate window.  Now I need to get the letters before and
after the Cursor Position in the Document.  So here I have
used GetSelection to retrieve the selected text.  The problem is I am
not able to retrieve the caret position in the document (notepad).  Is there any specific way in which i can get the letter/text around the caret/cursor position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the start/end of the selection range without actually modifying the selection.